# Inverse Laplace of $\frac{K}{s(T s+1)}$

Tags: inverse-laplace

$$
y(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{K}{s(T s+1)}\right]
$$

I know it should be:
$$
K\left(1-e^{-t / T}\right)
$$

But I get:

$$
y(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{K}{s(T s+1)}\right] = [\text{partial fraction division}] = K \left( \mathcal{L}^{-1}\frac{1}{s} + \mathcal{L}^{-1}\frac{1-T}{sT+1} \right) = K\left( 1 + \frac{1}{T} \frac{1}{s + \frac{1}{T}} - \mathcal{L}^{-1}\frac{1}{T} T \frac{1}{s + \frac{1}{T}}  \right)= K \left( 1 + \frac{1}{T}e^{-1/T} - e^{-1/T} \right)= K \left( 1 + \frac{T-1}{T}e^{-1/T} \right)
$$

Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Without even going through all of it, your result should be a function of $t$.

Comment: Why that title?  This is not the inverse Laplace transform of $K$, is it?

Comment: Sorry indeed I did post too fast. Let me edit it. I am not sure how I can edit it though?

Comment: Click on the word *Edit.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your partial fraction decomposition is wrong. Note that $$\frac{K}{s(T s+1)} = \frac{K}{s} - \frac{KT}{sT+1} = \frac{K}{s} - \frac{K}{s+\frac{1}{T}} $$Now take the inverse transform which yields $$y(t) = Ku(t) - Ke^{-\frac{t}{T}}u(t) = Ku(t)(1-e^{-\frac{t}{T}})$$

Comment: @mjw I added the final answer, thanks.

Comment: Yes!${}{}{}{}{}$